# Input with edit button in angular/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

One of the inputs in my form needs to be edited separately from the rest of the form. Is there an easier way to do this with angular/bootstrap?

I've been working on it for a while and the css is a mess, and getting messier so I won't bore you with that. But here's the html:

```
<form>
    <div><input type="text" ng-model="input1"></div>
    <div><input type="text" ng-model="input2"></div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="input3.val" ng-disabled="!input3.isEditable">
        <input type="button" class="edit-button" ng-click="makeEditable(input3)"/>
    </div>
    <div><input type="text" ng-model="input4"></div>
    <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Is there an easier way than coding by hand to do something like this:
[image]

Comment: When you say "One of the inputs in my form needs to be edited separately from the rest of the form", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: what do you mean by "coding it by hand"?

Comment: @GrowingDev One input has a button (pictured in my post) which opens a modal that allows the user to select a value based on other criteria. The result of that modal populates the input (although it's still editable), which - with the other inputs' values - is submitted with the form.

Comment: @darham I mean it's taking forever to code this thing, and it seems to me that it's fairly common enough that it might be accomplished more easily with angular/bootstrap, rather than writing the wrapping div, all the inputs, all the classes, getting the background image just right, making an input that takes up 100% of the width, but still has a button to the right of it. It's not like it's difficult, just time-consuming, so I'm wondering if there's an alternative.

Comment: bootstrap does have a solution for you in that case checkout the documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

Comment: @durham Awesome, if you put this as an answer I can give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add below css, to place the edit button as shown in the above image.

```
.container, .inputText {
  position: relative;
 }


 .edit-button {
   position: absolute;
   right: -3px; 
   top:0
}
```

http://jsbin.com/voxeva/edit?html,css,console,output

Comment: That's not going to work because the button is on top of the text input, and the input needs to be 100% width.

Comment: #Travis Heeter Can you let me know if this solution works ?

Comment: @darham 's solution in the comments to the original post was what I was looking for. That's not to say your solution doesn't work, but it didn't answer the question of whether it was able to be done in bootstrap, which is what he provided. Thanks anyway!